# Iterating and counting across class variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, hashmap

I have class, which contains variables of multiple type, most of those (about 30) are double:

```
String something;
double x;
double y;
double z;
...
```

I want to iterate over doubles, but also keep them written in this "classic way", not inside array, because derived classes use most of them. The function I am having problem with now is how to iterate across all the double type variables, find how many of those are non zero and then pick one of all these variables randomly. There will be thousands of instances of this class and as I said, there are classes that expand this one. So I am working on solution, preferably something like pseudo:

```
nonzeros = 0
foreach doubleVarInClass variable
{
    if (variable != 0)
    nonzeros++;
}
if (nonzeros < parameter)
{
    randomDoubleVarInClass = random.next(...);
}
```

One solution which I was thinking about was to use HashMap to keep all the variables in, but then I will have to rewrite all classes that uses this one and not sure how it will affect performance, since it will be pretty intensively used all the time. Should I be afraid of performance and try something with classic arrays perhaps? I'd like to atleast keep variable names if nothing. I thought about array with references to these variables, so I can keep them written this way, not sure if its possible due to value passing in Java.

Also maybe there is some structure that keeps info about how many of those are non zero or have efficient function for it?

Thank you for any info that could solve my problem :)

Comment: "Should I be afraid of performance and try something with classic arrays perhaps?" - it will probably be used less intensively than you think. Also it seems like a name -> value mapping is what your algorithm calls for, so use that.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203203/how-might-i-count-the-number-of-int-members-defined-for-a-java-class) with interesting answers posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using reflection for this. Suppose you have instance of your class named `o`:

```
int nonzeros = 0;
for (Field f : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
  f.setAccessible(true);
  if (f.getType().equals(Double.TYPE) && f.getDouble(o) != 0.0) {
    nonzeros++;
  }
}
```

NOTE: Java Reflection will probably be bad idea from the point of performance, and you should test this first, from that point of view. Besides that, this provide easy checks without any changes in your class definition. In Java 6 performance of reflection is little better than on older versions, and you should check this in your personal use case and in your environment.

Comment: This will in all likelihood be slower than a hashmap.

Comment: Maybe but as SO say "I want to iterate over doubles, but also keep them written in this "classic way", not inside array, because derived classes use most of them", I don't think there is another solution without changing structure of classes.

Comment: I also edited the answer as I'm aware of this minus of reflection.

Comment: Well its not THAT needed, but I thought that if I will call these variables so many times from many other classes by well.. strings as keys in hashmap, that it will be slow. If its the faster way and I should rewrite all classes that use it well.. if its worth it then I guess I will.

Comment: @wolf "strings as keys in hashmap, that it will be slow" - why? Strings are immutable, so the hash codes are likely cached. This means the overhead of using a hashmap over a field is usually one getter call, one modulo operation, and one primitive unboxing. That's in and of itself not terrible, and I'm guessing that all of those are can be inlined by the JIT if this really is a hotspot.